# Display mode for search API users index

Tags: views, search, display-suite

I have Search API users index. I am trying to show them in views with my display mode (for example 'teaser') created by [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

But I only can show fields. For default user view I can show all modes: fields, display suite, rendered entity and so on.

How I can show them via rendered entity?

Comment: I don't know how. Maybe `drush up -y` helps me. But now i can select Rendered Entity.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Clear the site's cache (drush cc all)
2. Re-index the search api index that powers the view
3. Refresh the view edit page

After that you should see the "Rendered entity" option appear with your view modes as options.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [View php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)

put custom code in it and fetch data from database using predefined variables in it

Comment: I need only display mode, which is standart for views. Views PHP is not good solution. In this way better not use views and create page programmatically with search API and display in mode which i need.

Comment: @Niklan you want to create searching API using view