# Rendered Entity not apearing under Show

Tags: views, 8, search

I created a new index and I've created a view with it but it only has the options to show as `Search Results` & `Fields`. Is there something that has to be done when configuring the index to get `Rendered Entity` to show up on views?

It does show up with the Default Content Index made with the module but whenever I make a new index and create a view with it isn't an option.

Pictures:
What appears when creating a view with the default index(1) vs an index that I created(2).

[image: What appears when creating a view with the default index]

[image: What appears when creating a view with an index that I created]

Comment: I think you need to be indexing a field that requires the rendered entity for it to be available, for example the _Rendered HTML output_ field

Comment: I do have a Rendered HTML output field but it still doesn't give the option. I tried changing a few of the view mode options in the field and tried making it the same as the default but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. I found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165410/). All I needed was to flush all caches.